# Compress Audio upon writing to file

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to create a recorder from audio coming out from soundcard and this is my progress so far, the problem is the recorded audio when saving to file is so large like a song can reach up to hundreds of megabyte.

here's my code

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Record_From_Soundcard
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        private WaveFileWriter writer;
        private WasapiLoopbackCapture waveInSel;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            MMDeviceCollection deviceCol = deviceEnum.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active);

            cboAudioDrivers.DataSource = deviceCol.ToList();
        }       

        private void btnStopRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            waveInSel.StopRecording();
            writer.Close();
        }        

        private void btnStartRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SaveFileDialog _sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                _sfd.Filter = "Mp3 File (*.mp3)|*.mp3";               

                if (_sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    MMDevice _device = (MMDevice)cboAudioDrivers.SelectedItem;
                    waveInSel = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(_device);
                    writer = new WaveFileWriter(_sfd.FileName, waveInSel.WaveFormat);                    

                    waveInSel.DataAvailable += (n, m) =>
                    {
                        writer.Write(m.Buffer, 0, m.BytesRecorded);
                    };

                    waveInSel.StartRecording();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

can anyone help me on how to compress audio upon saving?

maybe it will be added on this part

```
waveInSel.DataAvailable += (n, m) =>
    {
         writer.Write(m.Buffer, 0, m.BytesRecorded);
    };
```

Thanks in advance.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Try this using naudio dll

```
Using NAudio.Wave; Using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;Using NAudio.Lame
Private void WaveToMP3(int bitRate = 128){
    String waveFileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Temporal\mix.wav";
    String mp3FileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\Grabaciones\ " + Strings.Format(DateTime.Now, "dd-MM-yyyy.HH.mm.ss") + ".mp3";

    Using (var reader = New AudioFileReader(waveFileName))
    {
        Using (var writer = New LameMP3FileWriter(mp3FileName, reader.WaveFormat, bitRate))
        {
            reader.CopyTo(writer);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code sample looks promising and is likely to help OP, but could be improved if it was in C# (since that's what the question is tagged as).

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an MP3 file by saving a WAV file with a .MP3 extension (which is what you are doing here). You will need to select an encoder available on your machine, and pass the audio through that. I go into some detail about how to do this with NAudio in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET).

Comment: i have this idea of encoding the result into mp3 but i always got an error **Please select a PCM WAV file to encode.** so maybe the created wav file is not completed? or not properly formatted to wav?

Comment: is there any code snippet that compact m.Buffer when Data is available in **waveInSel.DataAvailable**?